# Overlap controls with listbox

Tags: windows, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I'm trying to create a autocompletebox but it keeps moving items in my grid/stackpanel down while I want the listbox to overlap the controls, how can I prevent this from happening? I also want to say that a control may appear above the textbox. Thanks in advance.
[image: Without Items]
[image: Not overlapping with items]

XAML:

```
<Page
    x:Class="test.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:test"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:mmppf="using:Microsoft.PlayerFramework"
    xmlns:ab="using:AutoCompleteBox"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Name="rootGrid">

        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="panelScrollViewer" Height="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" ZoomMode="Disabled" MaxZoomFactor="1" MinZoomFactor="1">

            <StackPanel Name="contentPanel" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="20,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">

                <mmppf:MediaPlayer Name="player" Background="Black" Margin="0,0,0,40" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Top" Visibility="Collapsed"/>

                <TextBox Name="autocomplete" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>

                <ListBox Name="autoCompleteListbox" Grid.Row="0" 
                         ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"/>

                <StackPanel Name="menuPanel" Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <!--Contains Rows of stack panels with buttons-->
                </StackPanel>

                <ProgressRing Name="prLoading" Width="100" Height="100" Margin="50" Foreground="White" Visibility="Collapsed"/>

                <Grid Name="cv">
                    <!--more controls-->
                </Grid>
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

NOTE: The autocomplete textbox is a object that will show a listbox under it. Also have I found a workaround but if there is a better way to do it, please suggest.

SOLUTION:

```
<Page
    x:Class="test.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:test"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:mmppf="using:Microsoft.PlayerFramework"
    xmlns:ab="using:AutoCompleteBox"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Name="rootGrid">

        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="panelScrollViewer" Height="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" ZoomMode="Disabled" MaxZoomFactor="1" MinZoomFactor="1">

            <StackPanel Name="contentPanel" Margin="20,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <mmppf:MediaPlayer x:Name="player" Background="Black" Margin="0,0,0,40" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Top" Visibility="Collapsed"/>

                    <TextBox x:Name="autocomplete" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                </StackPanel>

                <Grid>
                    <StackPanel Margin="0" Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="1">
                        <StackPanel Name="menuPanel" Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                            <!--Contains Rows of stack panels with buttons-->
                        </StackPanel>

                        <ProgressRing Name="prLoading" Width="100" Height="100" Margin="50" Foreground="White" Visibility="Collapsed"/>

                        <Grid Name="cv">
                            <!--more controls-->
                        </Grid>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <ListBox Name="autoCompleteListbox" Grid.Row="0" 
                             VerticalAlignment="Top"
                             ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"/>
                </Grid>
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: Have you tried to add a layer above the controls? Your host page would need to contain a grid for example that contains a grid and a canvas. They'd both be in the same cells, and the canvas would be added after so the z-index would be higher than the content grid (such that the canvas content would always be above the grid that holds the text box for example). If you needed to show something at absolute coordinates, you'd show it in the canvas, properly positioned.

Comment: I added the XAML, I hope I made it clear enough.